# Robots.txt Content displaying when accessing the website

Tags: asp.net, iis, server, robots.txt

When accessing the websites of our web server(IIS), it displays the robots.txt content and not the actual site. Would you know what is the cause and the resolution of this? [Screenshot of issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GWox.jpg)

Comment: How did you access your website? does it display actual site when you browse the website in iis?

Comment: I'm accessing our website in any browser. But instead of receiving the page as response. The server responds the robots.txt content. I've added the screenshot on the question for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Default page in web server(IIS) so that IIS express can Run that default page and not to show Robot.txt